# Extract PDF spreadsheet data into a Python data structure

Tags: python, pdf, extract

I have some PDF spreadsheets and was wanting to extract the data from each one into store it in something like a 2d list of strings; essentially recreating the table/spreadsheet from the PDF in the form of an object that I can index and use in my code. Is PDFMiner my best option for achieving something like this? It would be nice if the extraction from the table/spreadsheet could be done based on cells somehow rather than looking for spaces since it often happens that the tables will have empty cells in various locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the easy part: yes, [PDFMiner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/) is probably your best option :-)

The "probably" in the previous sentence should give you a hint... PDF extraction can be a kind of black magic; everything depends on how well-formed / predictable your source PDFs are.

If you're lucky, the quickest solution may be to use an established tool to transform the PDFs to some other format that can easily be parsed (HTML comes to mind) and then extract the tables from there. In fact that is exactly what [pdftable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdftable/) does...

Sometimes this may not work and you need to use the visual clues from the page to divide up the table cells. In that case, [pdfminer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/) comes in handy. It can tell you where all the text is situated and has things like a PostScript renderer to "draw" the lines that other extraction tools cannot see. [This blog post](http://blog.scraperwiki.com/2012/06/25/pdf-table-extraction-of-a-table/) explains how you may go about doing this.